# Solve $ \int_{0}^{y}{f(x)g(x,y)}dx=\int_{0}^{y}{h(x)}dx $

Tags: calculus, analysis

Here we get $$ \int_{0}^{y}{f(x)g(x,y)}dx=\int_{0}^{y}{h(x)}dx $$ where $ f(x),g(x,y),h(x) $ are all real functions. Let's suppose that they are all **smooth functions**.

I'd like to solve for $ f(x) $, and naturally, I take derivatives:
$$ G(x,y)=\int{f(x)g(x,y)}dx $$
$$ \implies G(y,y)-G(0,y)=\int_{0}^{y}{h(x)}dx 
\implies \frac{d(G(y,y)-G(0,y))}{dy}=h(y)$$
and we get $$ \frac{\partial G}{\partial x}(x,y)\bigg|_{x=y}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}(x,y)\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=y}=h(y) $$ $$ \implies f(y)g(y,y)+\int_{0}^{y}{f(x)\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y}}dx=h(y) $$
And I'm stuck here. My $ f(x) $ seems to be unsolvable for me.

Any attention or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a formal solution. Nothing can be done of $f(x)$ and  $g(x,y($ is not known nothing can be done further.

Comment: Thank you! I think this would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Provided $g(0,0) \ne 0$, this is solvable, but that doesn't mean there is necessarily some nice expression for the solution.

To see that it is solvable, at least over a significant space of functions, consider the case where "smooth" = "analytic". That is,
$$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i, \quad g(x,y) = \sum_{j,k = 0}^\infty b_{jk}x^jy^k, \quad h(y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_ny^n$$
Integrating your equation gives
$$\sum_{i,j,k} \frac{a_ib_{jk}}{i+j+1}y^{i+j+k+1} = \sum_n \frac{c_n}{n+1}y^{n+1}$$
which gives for each $n$
$$\sum_{i+j+k = n}\frac{a_ib_{jk}}{i+j+1} = \frac{c_n}{n+1}$$
Now $g$ and $h$ are known, and thus so are $b_{jk}$ and $c_n$, and we want to find $a_i$.  Since $i, j, k, n \ge 0$, we get the following equations:

- $n = 0:\quad a_0b_{00} = c_0$, which solves to $a_0 = \dfrac{c_0}{b_{00}}$
- $n = 1:\quad \dfrac {a_1b_{00}}2 + \dfrac{a_0b_{10}}2 + \dfrac{a_0b_{01}}1 = \dfrac{c_1}2$. Since we know $a_0$, this is easily solved for $a_1$.

$n = 2$ will provide a much longer sum. But there will be only one term in $a_2$, while all the other terms involve the already known values of $a_0$ and $a_1$. So again $a_2$ is uniquely determined. Similar remarks hold for all higher values of $n$.

Assuming convergence (note that $a_i$ is majorized by a certain sum of $c_n$ and various $b_{jk}$), this uniquely defines $f$.

Comment: I think if given g(0,0)=0, our f is also solvable in your way.

Comment: If $g(0,0) = 0$ then $b_{00} = 0$, and thus solving for each of the $a_k$ would involve division by $0$.

Comment: mmm…but $a_{0} $ is solved in the next equation (n=1) and so are the rest.($ a_{n} $ would be solved by equation (n+1))

Comment: No, each $a_k$ is determined by the equation for $n = k$. Equation $n=0$ gives $a_0$. After that. $a_0$ is a known quantity, which allows you to solve $n=1$ for $a_1$, and so on. But in the $n$-th equation $a_n$ appears with coefficient $b_{00}$. Thus to solve that equation for $a_n$, you have to divide by $b_{00}$ every time. So even when $b_{00}=c_0 = 0$, (which would allow you to choose a_0 to be anything), you still have to divide by $b_{00}$ for the higher $a_n$. This whole process breaks down when $g(0,0) = 0$.

Comment: Ahh…Let me explain: Although $ b_{00}=0 $ as well as $ c_{0}=0 $, we don't get $a_{0}$ here, but in the equation$(n=2)$, $b_{00}=0$ makes $a_{0}$ clear, and the same thing goes on in the equation$(n+1)$, the coefficient of $a_{n+1}$ is $b_{00}=0$, it is able to solve $a_{n}$.

Comment: Yeah - you are right, if $b_{00} = 0$, you can just solve the $n+1$ equation to find $a_n$ instead, unless $g$ has some very strong symmetries.